# How to set up Parse client side push notifications

Tags: swift, parse-platform, certificate, provisioning-profile

I am trying to set up push notifications with Parse on a test project.

I have followed the push setup tutorial / guides.

I have enabled client pushes in the Parse dashboard.
[image]

I have updated the .plist

I have set the code signing settings in build settings for target and project.

I send a push by:

```
PFPush.sendPushMessageToChannelInBackground("global", withMessage: "First push ever") { (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
 ...
}
```

When I try send a push I get the following error

```
Error Domain=Parse Code=115 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 115.)" UserInfo=0x1764cad0 {code=115, error=Client-initiated push isn't enabled.}
```

from

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError)
```

Have I setup my provisioning profiles and certificates incorrectly? Is there a way to check this? Have I setup Parse in appDelegate incorrectly? Is there a way to check this?

My app delegate looks like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
 Parse.setApplicationId("xxx", clientKey: "xxx")
 var userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge)
 var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
 application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
 application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
 return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
 var currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
 currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
 currentInstallation.channels = ["global"]
 currentInstallation.save()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
 if error != nil {
  println(error)
 }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
 PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
 var currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
 if currentInstallation.badge != 0 {
 currentInstallation.badge = 0
 currentInstallation.saveEventually()
 }
```

Comment: How are you trying to send the push notification?  I have not started using Swift, but looking at your code, I don't see where you are sending the push notification from the client.  You only need to activate "Client push enabled" if your app is sending push notifications to other devices.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the push request

Comment: Error 115 means Push is misconfigured on the server. Have you configured your certificates on Parse? And are they the correct type (dev vs prod)? Parse should tell you in the push area which type of certs you have uploaded - make sure your app build is using the same type.

Answer (score 1):

You don't send client pushes from the app delegate. You send them from the action that triggers the push.

Here is an example in Objective C:

```
// Create our Installation query
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"channels" equalTo:@"Giants"]; // Set channel
[pushQuery whereKey:@"scores" equalTo:YES];

// Send push notification to query
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:pushQuery];
[push setMessage:@"Giants scored against the A's! It's now 2-2."];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

And fyi, if you're planning on shipping this app to the app store, you should use cloud code to handle the client side pushes, because direct client to client pushes open your app up to security vulnerabilities.